# How to check conditions before performing navigation segue

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I have a storyboard controlled app. On the register page, I want to send the user to the home page when pressing the register button. So i dragged a segue from the button to the home page. But then I cannot check conditions before the segue is performed. But if i create a segue and perform it programmatically, the home page comes over the register page, allowing the user to swipe back. Can someone tell me how to check conditions before that segue is performed, or not allow the user to go back to the register page if doing it programmatically. This is my storyboard. [Main.storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ni9Zc.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- Reconnect the segue from the **controller** to the destination.
- Connect the button to an IBAction.
- In the IBAction *check conditions* and call [`performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621413-performsegue) on success.

Comment: What should i call inside the shouldPerformSegue() function as it needs to return a Bool

Comment: As you wrote *check conditions*. Please click on the link and read the documentation.

Comment: I tried conditions just to test, still performs segue on the button click even if shouldPerformSegue returns false

Comment: Did you reconnect the segue? `shouldPerformSegue` works only after calling `performSegue` in code

Comment: Yes. I connected the segue from the view controller to the destination controller

Comment: Ok. Nevermind I just added the conditions to the IBAction function and it seemed to work alright. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode 12.0 Swift 5.0**

- First of all you need to connect "Register" button to an IBAction in your code;
- In the IBAction you can call function:
  `func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil)`.
- If in condition everything is succesfull you call this function otherwise `return` with error.

Example of sign out button:

```
private func showLoginViewController() {
    // Creates the view controller with the specified identifier
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginForm") as! LoginViewController
    let navigationVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    navigationVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    present(navigationVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// Tap on button
@IBAction func signOutUserButton(_: UIButton) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Are you sure you want to sign out?", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Sign Out", style: .destructive, handler: { _ in

        // Condition where I check possibility to sign out
        self.signOut()

    }))
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    present(alertController, animated: true)
}

private func signOut() {
    let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
    do {
        try firebaseAuth.signOut()

        // If everything is okay then perform segue
        showLoginViewController()

    } catch let signOutError as NSError {

        // Otherwise show error
        print("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)

    }
}
```